# Stream audio with JS - audio buffer coming from Python

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, web-audio-api

I have a Python script that generates an audio buffer every 170 ms. I would like to live stream this audio on a webpage.

What's the easiest way to do so? Should I create a socket between the JS and the Python codes (with 'net'?) and then treat the buffer in JS? Is there an even easier way I can't think of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets and put the data into an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer). This will allow you to send binary data to the webpage, process it in JavaScript and play it. You can either use a library for implementing the websocket server or a library that integrates with your web framework if you're using one.

That said, an easier method could be just sending an HTTP audio stream and playing it with the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: 1/ Sending an HTTP audio stream ? How to ? It seems like aood idea but I don't know how to do that. I will investigate.

2/ I tried the socket option but I have a problem. Since I can't add data in the buffer once it's being played, I can't play the sound in real time. And if I play multiple buffers, it stutters.